Luks header corrupted
I have a Sabrent backup disk (FDE LUKS) which I mounted during install as I couldn't mount it after install, so I reinstalled MX23 with the disk mounted and encrypted it during install, so I have the pop-up asking for password.
The other day, while moving devices around, I involuntarily unplugged the disk, I re-plugged it right away, it asked me for the password, entered, unlocked, fine.
But the USB cable was not right and it unplugged again. I re-plugged it, it asked me for password, and ... couldn't unlock it since.
Of course, I don't have backup.
I give up, I've accepted I've lost all data
Now I would like to create a new header with new passphrase so I can get my backup disk back up and running and start over
How do I create a new header + passphrase but keep the partitioning as-is so it stay in the boot pop-up (asking for passphrase) ?
